# The simplist jQuery menu to select the html for an empty div

Tags: jquery

I have a  with about six `<li>`'s  ... I want each  to be a menu choice, you know, as usual with a link color and a hover color. Any selected `#ThisStory` clicked loads ThisStory.html into an empty division called `#storyDiv`.. Upon making another selection, html of the new id overwrites the previous content of `#storyDiv`.

I know this is basic, but I seem to be lower than basic..

I've seen something like this done by wrapping each menu item with a , I think, and giving the span an id?? or some such... 
Must it be done so round about? Can't each element `<li>` directly be given an id?

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to:

```
$('ul#myMenueId li a').bind('click', function(){
  $('#myTargetDiv').load($(this).attr('href'));
  return false;
}
```

The function must return false to prevent the browser from loading it into the parent window.